# How do I make and if else statement for individual radio buttons?

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, radio-button

I have this code that creates radio buttons, can someone show me the code to select each button separately when a radio button is check on an If Else statement when I click a button please?. How can I make the text of each radio button different?

```
private void createButtons()
        {
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
            for(int i = 0;i <10;i++)
            {
                RadioButton b = new RadioButton();
                b.Name = i.ToString();
                b.Text = "radiobutton" + i.ToString();
                b.AutoSize = true;
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The text of each button is already different. You are appending a number to the end as you move through your `for` loop. It sounds like you just need to add a handler on the [`CheckedChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event of your dynamically created radio buttons so you can do something based on the one which is clicked.

You would just need to add this line to the build steps in your `for` loop:

```
b.CheckedChanged += RadioButtonClicked;
```

And then define the appropriate method:

```
private void RadioButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var radioButton = (RadioButton)sender;

    // Only run on checked items (per your comments).
    // This condition will cause the uncheck action/event to exit here.
    if (!radioButton.Checked)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Alternately, you could use a switch statement.
    if (radioButton.Name == "1")
    {
        // do something...
    }
    else if (radioButton.Name == "2")
    {
        // do something else...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Jason, I tried it and it's working for me.

Comment: Something is wrong, when I go from radio button1 to 2, it fires radio button one again and then 2.

Comment: @dominique1256 This is because as one is checked, the other is unchecked. You may want to add a condition that makes sure the sender object is the checked one.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, I suggest using a regular `Button` instead of the `RadioButton`.

Here is an implementation to display a unique Message for each one:

```
private void createButtons()
{
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 65; i++)
    {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Name = i.ToString();
        b.Text = "Translate" + i.ToString();
        b.Click += b_Click;
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b);
    }
}

void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = sender as Button;

    string TextBoxValue = string.Empty;

    switch (b.Name)
    {
        case "1":
            TextBoxValue = "Get the Translation for item # 1 here";
            break;
        case "2":
            TextBoxValue = "Get the Translation for item # 2 here";
            break;
        // ETC....  3,4,5
        default:
            TextBoxValue = "Button #(" + b.Name + ") is not handled";
            break;
    }

    MessageBox.Show(this, TextBoxValue, "Translation");
}
```

Comment: Something is wrong, when I go from radio button1 to 2, it fires radio button one again and then 2. – Dominique1256 just now   edit

Comment: By putting all the RadioButtons into the same panel, they are automatically grouped together.  Because they are grouped together, only one of them is allowed to be "Checked" at a time.  Therefore it UN-Checks the last one that was previously checked and fires the CheckChanged event for both.    If you look at my code, it checks for the "Checked" property and let's you decide what to write as the text.    

If you want to allow multiple to be Checked at once, then you should use CheckBoxes instead of RadioButtons.

Comment: @Don-It is not working for me either. For Jason's solution when I check radio button2 after radio button 1. Radion button1 one fires again when I click ok one the messagebox and then messagebox for radion button2 fires.

Comment: I think I understand, what I want is when I check radion button2 after radio button1 I don't want to see radio button1 fire again. Is the solution to not use a Panel?

Comment: CHECKING Button 2 will auto UNCHECK Button 1 and the CheckCHANGED event is going to fire for both.  Do you want to allow multiple to be checked - or only one at a time?  OR do you only want to change the text for the one that is checked?     It depends what you want.   You could try registering with the CLICK event only.      Change the    b.CheckedChanged += b_CheckedChanged;    TO    b.Click += b_CheckedChanged;   OR  only handle the if (b.Checked == true) and take code out of the ELSE section.

Comment: I am sorry for being clearer. I just want the dynamic button to behave like when a drag a button on the form. When I check radio button1 on click GO I see a messagebox. then if I check radio button2 I see a messagebox for that radio button. I need them to respond separately. And since dynamic button only show at run time and don't understand how to have the name of all radio unique.AS per my code above all radio buttons have the text as "radiobutton" I don't want that.

Comment: In your code you set the name as  b.Text = "radiobutton" + i.ToString();  (IE: 'radiobutton1', 'radiobutton2', etc..)   They are uniquely named with the number.  I think you want to only run code when checked (and NOT UnChecked)  And then run some code that is unique for each?   So, you should change to the Click event and then in your event handler put an if(b.Name = "radiobutton1") for each button.   OR don't create them with a loop, just add one at a time and make a unique event handler for each button.  If that doesn't work, please describe your overall goal.

Comment: @Don-I really appreciate you taking the time to help me. I have a winform app that requires 65 radio buttons, they represent 65 contract clauses. When  User wants to see the English translation of the French contract clauses he checks the appropriate radio button. Then when the click event button is clicked if pulls the translated English clause from the database into a textbox. Someone in this forum told me that they would never use 65 radio button on the designer whether created dynamically or otherwise but he never explained why.

Comment: I have 65 of these if else statement.                                                              if (comboBox1.Text == "CHUM" && radioButton1.Checked)
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(cmd1.ExecuteReader());
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                    textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();

                }

Comment: I updated the answer, please let me know if that is a better solution.  thanks.